# How can I "URL decode" a string in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: url, emacs, elisp, urlencode, urldecode

I've got a string like "foo%20bar" and I want "foo bar" out of it.

I know there's got to be a built-in function to decode a URL-encoded string (query string) in Emacs Lisp, but for the life of me I can't find it today, either in my *lisp/* folder or with Google.

What is it called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`org-link-unescape` does the job for very simple cases ... `w3m-url-decode-string` is better, but it isn't built in and the version I have locally isn't working with Emacs 23.

Comment: That's good enough for now.  It is strange that it uses only a constant list of 17 chars, though.  Maybe I'll fix that sometime.

Comment: `url-unhex-string` does what you want.

Answer (score 50):

```
url-unhex-string
```

Comment: I've got a url-unhex-string no match with Emacs 25 :/

Comment: You may need to (require 'url-util) -- in practice, this will often be done by some other code loading but certainly not good to rely on that.

Answer (score 30):

In my case I needed to do this interactively. The previous answers gave me the right functions to call, then it was just a matter of wrapping it a little to make them interactive:

```
(defun func-region (start end func)
  "run a function over the region between START and END in current buffer."
  (save-excursion
    (let ((text (delete-and-extract-region start end)))
      (insert (funcall func text)))))

(defun hex-region (start end)
  "urlencode the region between START and END in current buffer."
  (interactive "r")
  (func-region start end #'url-hexify-string))

(defun unhex-region (start end)
  "de-urlencode the region between START and END in current buffer."
  (interactive "r")
  (func-region start end #'url-unhex-string))
```

Add salt, I mean bind to keys according to taste.

Answer (score 11):

Emacs is shipped with a [URL library](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UrlPackage) that provides a bunch of URL parsing functions—as [huaiyuan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611831/how-do-decode-url-in-emacs-lisp/613925#613925) and [Charlie Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611831/how-do-decode-url-in-emacs-lisp/611912#611912) already pointed out. Here is a small example that'd give you an idea how to use it:

```
(let ((url "http://www.google.hu/search?q=elisp+decode+url&btnG=Google+keres%E9s&meta="))
  ;; Return list of arguments and values
  (url-parse-query-string
   ;; Decode hexas
   (url-unhex-string
    ;; Retrieve argument list
    (url-filename
     ;; Parse URL, return a struct
     (url-generic-parse-url url)))))
=> (("meta" "") ("btnG" "Google+keresés") ("/search?q" "elisp+decode+url"))
```

I think is better to rely on it rather than [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) as it *is* its main purpose to parse a URL.

Comment: love this example!

Answer (score 3):

You can grab `urlenc` from [MELPA](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MELPA) and use `urlenc:decode-region` for a region or `urlenc:decode-insert` to insert your text interactively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it a little too hard: `split-string` will probably do most of what you want.  For fancier stuff, have a look at the functions in `url-expand.el`; unfortunately, many of them don't have doc-strings, so you may have to read code.

`url-generic-parse-url` looks like a potential winner.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misspoke.  I've got a string like "foo%20bar" and I want "foo bar" out of it.  I don't see how split-string or url-generic-parse-url or anything in url-expand.el really helps here.