# Browser-Style FTP URL Recognition in Emacs

Tags: url, emacs, ftp, minibuffer

Has anybody found any way to make Emacs minibuffer input, such as in `find-file`, correctly detect/recognise and access standard ftp-urls such as

```
ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/
```

instead of having to, by hand, convert it to to emacs's own format

```
/ftp:anonymous@gcc.gnu.org:/pub/gcc/infrastructure/
```

before typing it into the minibuffer.

This would make Emacs even more accessible as a file manager when transparently working with FTP directories.

Comment: The decoding tips in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611831/how-to-url-decode-a-string-in-emacs-lisp?rq=1 may be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

would like to see that as a feature request sent by

M-x report-emacs-bug